# The SECRET_KEY setting must not be empty

Tags: python, django

A la hora de crear un registro de usuario personalizado en django de la siguiente forma:
-Creando una app que contenga los modelos de mi clase usuario
-Dentro, en el archivo **models** crear una clase (la cual hereda de **AbstractBaseUser**):

```
class Usuario(AbstractBaseUser):
    NombreUsuario = models.CharField('nombre de usuario', max_length=100, unique=True)
    Nombre = models.CharField('Nombre', max_length=100)
    Apellidos = models.CharField('Apellidos', max_length=200)
    Email = models.EmailField('Correo electronico', unique=True)
    Password = models.CharField('Contraseña')
    NumeroTelefono = models.IntegerField('Numero de telefono', max_value=9, blank=True, null=True)
    FotoPerfil = models.ImageField('Foto de perfil', upload_to='C:/Users/Lenovo/Desktop/Isthetime/imageneslogo', max_length=100)
    UsuarioActivo = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    UsuarioAdministrador = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    Objects = UsuarioManager()
    USERNAME_FIELD = 'NombreUsuario'
    REQUIRED_FIELD = ['Nombre', 'Apellidos', 'Email', 'Password', 'NumeroTelefono']

    def has_perm(self, perm, obj=none):
        return True

    def has_module_perm(self, isthetime_label):
        return True 

    @property
    def is_staff(self):
        return self.UsuarioAdministrador
```

Y definiendo una clase para crear el usuario, heredando de BaseUserManager :

```
class UsuarioManager(BaseUserManager):
    def create_user( self, NombreUsuario, Nombre, Apellidos, Email, Password, NumeroTelefono):
        if not Email:
            raise ValueError('Introduce contraseña PUTO')
        user = Usuario(
              NombreUsuario = NombreUsuario,
              Nombre = Nombre,
              Apellidos= Apellidos,
              Email = self.normalize_email(Email), 
              Password = Password,
              NumeroTelefono = NumeroTelefono
               )

        user.set_password(Password)
        user.save()
        return user
```

Despues en el modulo settings agregando lo siguiente :

```
AUTH_USER_MODEL = `Usuario.Usuario´
```

Me aparece un error :

**raise ImproperlyConfigured("The SECRET_KEY setting must not be empty.")
django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: The SECRET_KEY setting must not be empty.**

He comprobado mi SECRET_KEY y no esta vacía, entonces no entiendo cual es el problema

Comment: Esas no son comillas, sino acentos en tu AUTH_USER_MODEL

Answer (score 0):

> AUTH_USER_MODEL = `Usuario.Usuario´   Esas no son comillas, sino acentos

**Cámbialo por esto**

```
AUTH_USER_MODEL = "Usuario.Usuario" 


AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'Usuario.Usuario'
```

Comment: si me equivoque en la pregunta en el codigo esta bien escrito, el problema era que habia que añadir la app en el modulo settings.py